# Have patent trolls ever gone after an individual?

Tags: patent-infringement

When publishing mobile apps, both on Android and IOS, one has the choice of registering as an individual, or as a company -- presumably an LLC.

Is it legal to assert a patent against an individual who has no "registered" business entity?

If so, is there any precedent whereby an individual has been sued by a patent troll?

Comment: "or as a company -- presumably an LLC" uh, I don't think you become a company just by checking a box. I'rd rather assume that you have then checked that box wrongfully.

Comment: @DonQuiKong My consulting is done through an LLC. I could potentially sell an app as an individual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Is it legal to assert a patent against an individual who has no "registered" business entity?**

I'm  not a lawyer, but I believe you are just as open to a infringement suit if you are an individual as a registered business. Indeed as an LLC you might be less of a target since that structure protects your family assets and makes you a less lucrative target.

**If so, is there any precedent whereby an individual has been sued by a patent troll?**

I'm not aware of one, but it is a [well known tactic](https://www.inc.com/minda-zetlin/patent-trolls-target-small-businesses-with-lawsuit-threats-heres-how-one-startup-fought-back.html) of trolls to target small business users of "infringing" technology. The idea is that small businesses using the technology are more likely to settle for small amounts than fight a suit compared to suing the large manufacturers. [This page](https://www.investopedia.com/articles/investing/071515/who-are-patent-trolls-how-do-they-work.asp) makes the following statement supporting the likelihood of suits against individuals.

> Unlike operating companies that use their patents to produce and sell
>   their product, patent trolls often acquire patents cheaply from
>   bankrupt companies and do not use those patents in operations, but
>   rather charge licensing fees to other businesses **and individuals** that
>   appear to infringe upon a patent that they own.